# Вывод даты и времени в текстовом виде

Tags: java, timestamp

Есть таблица, где хранится дата в TimeShamp сохраняла так: В частности текущее значение TimeShamp для данной записи `1574610262000`

```
mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
```

Нужно в список вывести теперь дату в читабельном виде. Делаю так, но вместо времени выходит непонятно что.

```
Date date = new Date(item.getDate()*1000L);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy mm:hh");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date.getTime());
```

> Отображается 24.11.2019 44:03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё выводится правильно. Просто Вы перепутали часы и минуты. Попробуйте так:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо.